# Render partial through link in form_for using jquery ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, form-for

hie, 
I have used multistep form in my application

I am giving link to render partial in my form_for tag.

My html code is,

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <%= form_for @subscribe , :validate => true, :html=>{:id=>"main_form"} do |f| %>
    <ul class='carosel_buttons inline'>
        <li class='circle active'>
            <h2><%= link_to "1", date_path, :remote => true %></h2>
        </li>
        <li class='circle'>
            <h2><%= link_to "2", booking_path, :remote => true %></h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
  <div class="item">
    <%= render "#{@subscribe.current_step}_step", :f => f %>
  </div>
</div>
```

i want to render date partial on click of "1" using link_to tag using ajax.

Now my controller i have,

```
def date
  respond_to do |format|               
    format.js
  end
end
```

and have corresponding date.js.erb file as,

```
$('.item').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'date_step', :f => f ) %>");
```

with partial file

```
<div class="field offset2" id="date">
  <%= f.label :date %><br />
  <%= f.hidden_field :start_date, :id=>"set_start_date" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :end_date, :id=>"set_end_date" %>
  <div id='datepicker'> </div>
</div>
```

but when i click on 1,

**ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#:0x007fb87ae09748>):
    1: $('.item').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'date_step', :f => f ) %>");**

i know it's because in my js.erb file i am not able to link :f=>f...

Can you please tell me how to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try  `:f => Proc.new {|f| form_for @subscribe}`

Comment: hey thnx for reply.. bt its giving me error as, ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `label' for #<Proc:0x007fba052fc878>):
    1: <div class="field offset2" id="brand">
    2:   <%= f.label :date %><br />
    3:   <%= f.hidden_field :start_date, :id=>"set_start_date" %>
    4:   <%= f.hidden_field :end_date, :id=>"set_end_date" %>
    5:   <div id='datepicker'> </div>

Comment: I have another idea how this might work, but I'm really not sure, If you are intrested, I will provide an answer

Comment: @JoeHalfFace: yeah sure..

Answer (score 0):

In your html you are using the @subscribe object and passing it to f, but f is not defined on the scope of the date controller, and nor in the date.js.erb.

I would recommend to render all the form in the partial (with form_for helper included) and in the controller (in date function) you can set the @subscribe variable with a Subscribe.new or finding it with the params (Subscribe.find(params[:id])

If this solution doesn't work for you, tell me!